# How to find expectation of coins

Tags: probability

We toss the coin twice. The probability of presenting the figure is 60%, while the number is 40%. Determine the expectation $E(X)$ of the common variable $X$ - the number is presented.

My attemp is: since the coin has only two possibilities i.e., $N$ and $F$. After being thrown twice, then the chances are $\Omega=\{NN, NF, FN, NN\}\rightarrow n(\Omega)=4.$ From here we have:

$P(X=0)=P(\{NN\})=\frac{1}{4}$

$P(X=1)=P(\{NN, NF, FN\})=\frac{3}{4}$

$P(X=2)=P(\{NF, FN, FF\})=\frac{3}{4}$

Now from here we can find:

$E(X)=\sum_i x_ip_i (x)=0\cdot\frac{1}{4}+1\cdot \frac{3}{4}+2\cdot \frac{3}{4}=\frac{9}{4}$

But i didnt know is it correct answers. Please help me. Thanks for my hard.

Comment: help me, please, to know if the solution is good or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't calculate the probabilities by the number of cases, since the heads and tails (number and figure) aren't equal. Instead you have to calculate (for example)
$$P(NF)=P(N)\cdot P(F) = 0.4\cdot 0.6 =0.24$$

Another thing is that you've included NN in X=1 and also in X=0, when only latter is correct. Of the X=2 cases only FF is correct.

Comment: can you choose it in detail please, user3010768, can you help me to solve th details

Comment: So, $X$ is how many numbers you get when you toss the coin twice.You have four alternative outcomes, as you said, NN, NF, FN and FF. 

First calculate the probabilites like I adviced in the answer. (If you don't know the method, you should go back to that subject, it's called "the product rule" or something like that).

Then count the Ns in each of these. If you toss NN you get two Ns. If you toss NF or FN, one N. If you toss FF, none of them.

Last, add up $p\cdot X$ like you did in your answer, but with the correct numbers.

Comment: do not want to say that the solution should be like this $P(X=0)=P(NN)=0.4\cdot 0.4=0.16$, $P(X=1)=P(NF,FN)=0.4\cdot 0.6+0.6\cdot 0.4=0.48$ and $P(X=2)=P(FF)=0.6\cdot 0.6=0.36$ or it's not good

Comment: That's the right solution if $X$ is the number of Fs. I may have confused Fs and Ns above, since their usually called heads and tails in English.

EDIT: And you should also multiply them with the outcome and add up:
$$0.16\cdot 0 + 0.48\cdot 1 + 0.36\cdot 2$$

Comment: X-present a number

Comment: who is the head (number) and tail(figure)

Comment: Then $P(X=0 ) = P(FF) = 0.16, P(X=1) = 0.48$ and $P(X=2)=0.16$, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107268/discussion-between-madrit-zhaku-and-user3010768).

Comment: $P(X=0)=P(FF)=0.6\cdot 0.6=0.36$, $P(X=1)=P(NF,FN)=0.4\cdot 0.6+0.6\cdot 0.4=0.48$ and $P(X=2)=P(NN)=0.4\cdot 0.4=0.16$ OR NOT

Comment: Those are the probabilities. Then go on to calculate the expectation like you did in your first solution.

Comment: now what is correct please: $$0\cdot 0.16+1\cdot 0.48+2\cdot 0.36 ....(1),$$ or $$0\cdot 0.36+1\cdot 0.48+2\cdot 0.16 ....(2),$$

Comment: who is okay (1) or (2), X-presented a number